# nested foreach loop break in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working with laravel. I have two table. one is `users` and another is `permission`. I have two `foreach` loop. One is to show user data. User data coming from `users` table. And another `foreach` loop is is for checking is that `user` available or not in `permission` table. 
I am fetching all user from `users` table like this:

```
    $allTeachers = User::where('role',2)->paginate(4);
```

And am also fetching all data from permission table like this.

```
$allpermiteds = Specialpermission::where('add_teacher','!=','NULL')->get();
```

I have sent those two query to my view. And it is working fine.
Now I am printing those users data in my view like this

```
@foreach($allteachers as $teacher)
            <tr> 
              <td>{{ $teacher->id}}</td>
              <td>{{ $teacher->name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $teacher->email }}</td>
              <td><button>give</button></td>
              <td><button>Remove</button></td>
@endforeach
```

I have printed two button there give and remove. Now I want to do that, If `$teacher->id` is available in the `permission` table `add_teacher` column then it should show `remove` button. Otherwise it should Show `add` button. 
I have done like this, But it is not working properly.

```
@foreach($allteachers as $teacher)
        <tr> 
          <td>{{ $teacher->id}}</td>
          <td>{{ $teacher->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $teacher->email }}</td>
          <td>@foreach($allpermitted as $p)
        @if($p->add_teacher == $teacher->id)
        <button>Remove</button>
        @else
       <button>give</button>
        @endif
@endforeach</td>
@endforeach
```

It shows a lot of button. If there are `4` users in the permission table then it will show `4` button for each `user`. That is the main problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, select `add_teacher` column from db, then convert your `Specialpermission` objects into array like below:

```php
$permissionData = Specialpermission::where('add_teacher','!=','NULL')->select('add_teacher')->get();
$allpermiteds   = collect($permissionData )->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray();
```

Then use `in_array` to check for permission check

```html
@foreach($allteachers as $teacher)

    <tr> 
      <td>{{ $teacher->id}}</td>
      <td>{{ $teacher->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $teacher->email }}</td>
      <td>
        @if(in_array($teacher->id,$allpermitted))
        <button>Remove</button>
        @else
       <button>give</button>
        @endif
    </td>

@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks, but it is only print `give` . I mean if condition is not working. If I do `{{dd($allpermitted)}}`  before if condition in view I can see those data. But if condition is not working . It print else condition .

Comment: @Fokrule: Try this: `@if(in_array($teacher->id, $allpermiteds))`

Comment: @HirenGohel both are same. If I send `$allpermiteds` then i should `$allpermiteds` and also if I send `$allpermited` to my view from controller then I should use `$allpermited` .

Comment: `$allpermitedsTmp   = collect($permissionData )->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray();` then `$allpermiteds= []; foreach($allpermitedsTmp   
 as $item){ $allpermiteds[] = $item->add_teacher; }` Now your $allpermiteds array contains only teachers id, now if (in_array()) logic will works.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the eloquent function `with` that defines the relationship between the two tables:

```php
$allTeachers = User::where('role',2)->with('SpecialPermisson')->paginate(4);
```

It will add a field of `SpecialPermission` (if it has). If not, it will give you a blank field, so check if its empty.

Comment: can you please explain some more kindly. I mean what will be eloquent relationship between those two table, and then how I should check if condition. please @sushant

Comment: @Fokrule in models that you define user and Special permisson you add a function that defines the relationship among them
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) see this link for more data 
It will always return data as usual with an extra field of specialPermisson 
you will see it if u dd the $allteachers
and check if the field is empty using the php empty function

Comment: yap if there are no special permission then it will show null